# Convert a 2D Convolution into a 1D Convolution + Affine Transformation in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, convolution

I have a particular Input with `Shape = [NxHxWxC_in]` and a kernel of `Size = [n_h,n_w,stride_h, stride_w]` with `C_out` number of filters (the strides can be 1 and 1 if that simplifies things but a general answer would be even better).

What is the most efficient way in TensorFlow of creating 1D Conv / Affine transformation layer combinations to get the same results as the 2D convolution ?

I have found something called a helix transform but I am unable to see whether this can be extended to multiple channels (with `C_in` and `C_out` being fairly large numbers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to use the [Helix Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_discrete_convolution#The_Helix_Transform) in order to create 1D convolution which is equivalence of multi dimensional convolution.

Comment: But that doesn’t reduce computational complexity, it seems. What is the purpose of this transform then?

Comment: It doesn't (Tough I don't know if it improves memory access patterns, I'm not an expert on that aspect). It is a representation trick the way I see it (Same ideas as building 2D Convolution in Matrix Form). But if you have a building block for 1D Convolution and you want to use it for N-D convolution, this is the way to go.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Though, if I understand correctly, you do end up doing a ton of multiplications by zero, since you pad the kernel to the same size as the input.